# why weight is changing regarding perceptron nn?

Tags: neural-network, perceptron

I am new to neuoro network, I am recently tried with neuro network perceptron,

I have two basic questions

1) It looks like the weight of the netowork gets changed each time I run.
2) I want to simulate a simple AND, and here is the weight I get

0.17206500126384902, 0.15035338347063618

The perceptron use step function as the transfer method.

I am wondering how to explain w1 = 0.17206500126384902 and w2 = 0.15035338347063618?

Comment: No code and way too broad. (But the answer is probably: random-number generators usually are initialized with a seed based on system-time -> two runs, maybe two different results).

Answer (score 0):

If you are training the neural network, the values of the weight should change every iteration (batch training) or after every training-sample of a interation (online training).

For a simple AND, the values you got are oke. It depends on the inital weights and thresholds you start with. If starting with other weights you result may be 0.1 for both input neurons. Actually the algorithm itself is not that hard:

**1. Initalize the weights and thresholds randomly**

For every iteration you have to:

**2. Calc the output for the specific input data** (so if you are training AND your input data will be (0,0), (0,1), (1,0) or (1,1)

[image: calc output]

**3. Calc the error and adujst the weights**

[image: calc new weights]

[image]

where e(p) is the error (differnce of output and correct output)

**4. repeat 2-3 for all input samples** ((0,0), (0,1), (1,0) and (1,1))

A lot of information about the topic how to calc or implement you can find here:
http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-10-neural-networks/